# Xamarin Shell - Hardware backbutton

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am testing https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals application on android 9.

I would like to know why the hardware back button does not work as expected (return to the previous view)

Example:

1. Start app
   2- Entered the Dogs tab
2. Press hardware back button
3. The application is suspended. You should go back to the cat list.

Example 2:

1. Start app
2. Entered the side menu and going to monkeys.
3. Press hardware back button
4. The application is suspended. You should go back to the cat list.

I'm not understanding why the hardware button only works correctly for example when I enter the detail of a cat and then I go back.

Answer (score 0):

Android hardware back button by default closes the currently opened activity and activates an activity from the navigation stack. If you want to override this behavior, you need to handle the back button press and implement the navigation you need for your use case. Shell has this handy feature implemented with `BackButtonBehavior` property:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior

Comment: It's frustrating that it's not the default behavior. The rest of the applications such as: Whatapp allows you to go back when you change the tab, Gmail allows you to return to the previous folder when you change the folder, and so it is with all applications  when you navigate through the side menu also returns to the previous screen. I think that is what any user expects by default.
It should save the entire application navigation stack, not just when navigating within master detail.

Comment: The hardware back button is not on iOS (available only on Android), while Shell is a cross-platform component that needs to take into account both platforms, thus the default implementation works as it is. Luckily the helper property allows you to skip diving into native code and activate the desired behavior in a cross-platform manner.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know why the hardware back button does not work as expected (return to the previous view) I'm not understanding why the hardware button only works correctly for example when I enter the detail of a cat and then I go back.

As I know, when a route from the Shell visual hierarchy is navigated to, a navigation stack isn't created. However, when a page that's not in the Shell visual hierarchy is navigated to, a navigation stack is created.

That's way the hardware back button does not work as you excepted.

Comment: I don't want to override the behavior. I want it to go to the previous screen.
And I can't make it go to the previous screen because the navigation stack is not saved anywhere, in those cases.